# Kind polymorphism in closed type families

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, type-families

I was trying to implement the type family `Ty` form the paper [Generic Programming of all Kinds](https://victorcmiraldo.github.io/data/hask2018_draft.pdf) which computes the type of an `Atom`. I first tried to use a closed type family just like what paper did:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module GenericK where

import Data.Kind

type Kind = Type

-- | TyVar represents type parameters that the data takes
data TyVar (zeta :: Kind) (k :: Kind) :: Type where
  VZ :: TyVar (x -> xs) x
  VS :: TyVar xs k -> TyVar (x -> xs) k

-- | Atom is similar to K1
data Atom (zeta :: Kind) (k :: Kind) :: Type where
  Var :: TyVar zeta k -> Atom zeta k
  Kon :: k -> Atom zeta k
  (:@:) :: Atom zeta (l -> k) -> Atom zeta l -> Atom zeta k

--| Gamma is a context
data Gamma (zeta :: Kind) where
  Eta :: Gamma Type
  (:&:) :: k -> Gamma ks -> Gamma (k -> ks)

type family Ty zeta (alpha :: Gamma zeta) (t :: Atom zeta k) :: k where
  Ty (k -> ks) (t :&: alpha) (Var VZ) = t
  Ty (k -> ks) (t :&: alpha) (Var (VS v)) = Ty ks alpha (Var v)
  Ty zeta alpha (Kon t) = t
  Ty zeta alpha (f :@: x) = (Ty zeta alpha f) (Ty zeta alpha x)
```

However, GHC complained:

```
• Expected kind ‘Atom zeta k’,
    but ‘f’ has kind ‘Atom zeta (k -> k)’
• In the third argument of ‘Ty’, namely ‘f’
  In the type ‘(Ty zeta alpha f) (Ty zeta alpha x)’
  In the type family declaration for ‘Ty’
```

The error message doesn't make much sense to me since clearly `f` should have kind `Atom zeta (l -> k)` and `x` should have kind `Atom zeta l`.

So I tried to use an open type family and it worked:

```
type family Ty zeta (alpha :: Gamma zeta) (t :: Atom zeta k) :: k

type instance Ty (k -> ks) (t :&: alpha) (Var VZ) = t
type instance Ty (k -> ks) (t :&: alpha) (Var (VS v)) = Ty ks alpha (Var v)
type instance Ty zeta alpha (Kon t) = t
type instance Ty zeta alpha (f :@: x) = (Ty zeta alpha f) (Ty zeta alpha x)
```

I'm curious why the closed type family didn't work. I guess this might have to do with kind polymorphism, but I don't really know how kind checking works in GHC.

Comment: The closed type family version compiles for me if I add the kind annotation `type family Ty (zeta :: Kind) ...` which seems to be implied by the declaration `data Gamma (zeta :: Kind)`. I have no idea why.

Comment: Yep explicitly adding a kind signature works, not sure if this is a bug of GHC tho...